# Complex Excel formula HELP please

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate annual mileage for each vehicle on an excel spreadsheet that has a list of different vehicles and their odometer entries.

Can you please recommend a formula that calculates the difference between the smallest and the biggest value in a range of cells in column B only when there is the same vehicle unit number listed in column A.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Aggregate Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$18/($A$2:$A$18=D2),1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$18/($A$2:$A$18=D2),1)
```

[image]

The first finds the largest number the second the smallest where the Vehicle number matches that in column D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=MAX(IF(D2=$A$2:$A$15,$B$2:$B$15))-MIN(IF(D2=$A$2:$A$15,$B$2:$B$15))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]